# Android How do I check the number of files in a directory

Tags: android, android-file

I am creating a directory in internal memory of device for storing files for application use.I am using:

```
File dir = context.getDir(userfavorites, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

The above code will create a new directory if it does not exists or returns me the existing file object if directory has already been created.What I want to check is the number and name of files this directory contains.How do I use this file object to accomplish this task.

NOTE:I don't want to use external memory of device.And I can't avoid creating directory as well because the files in directory has to be separated from other files that are not in directory.

UPDATED CODE:

```
private static boolean IsFoldercontainsFiles(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File dir = context.getDir(USER_FAV, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (dir.exists()) {
                    if (dir.listFiles() == null){
                     return false;} //it never execute this line even though its null
                    else{
            File childfile[] = dir.listFiles();
            Log.i("file no is ", Integer.toString(childfile.length));
            if (childfile.length == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
                }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check the [`listFiles`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) method of [`File`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) that will give you the list of children.

Comment: But if i check if (dir.listFiles() == null) then it always say its not null even though thr is nothing in the directory.Am I checking the wrong way for null check?Please help

Answer (score 11):

```
    File file=new File("/mnt/sdcard/yourfolder");
        File[] list = file.listFiles();
        int count = 0;
        for (File f: list){
            String name = f.getName();
            if (name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".some media extention"))
               count++;
            System.out.println("170 " + count);
        }
```

Comment: Yours should be accepted as you have told how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
File childfile[] = dir .listFiles();
for (File file2 : childfile) {
    Log.v("file name is ", file2.getName());
}
```

here listFiles() return all the childfiles for the "dir" and iterating this will help you to get the names of the childfiles

Comment: But if i check if (dir.listFiles() == null) then it always say its not null even though thr is nothing in the directory.Am I checking the wrong way for null check?Please help

Comment: once have a look at this.. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles() . I think according to this the method listFiles() returns null only if the particular file is not a directory

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
File dir = new File(path); // "/mnt/sdcard/yourfolder"

long totalNumFiles = dir.listFiles().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample of code for getting number of files in a directory

```
private int getNumberOfFiles() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File outFile = new File(outFolder);
    if (!outFile.exists())throw new FileNotFoundException();
    int numberofFiles = outFile.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return (file.getPath().startsWith("frame_")&&(file.getPath().endsWith(".jpg")||file.getPath().endsWith(".jpeg")));
        }
    }).length;
    return numberofFiles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`listFiles`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#listFiles()) method of the [`File`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File) class returns *an array of File objects, one for each file or directory in the directory*.

One can use recursion to find all files within a directory and its subdirectories.

```kotlin
fun File.getFileCountRecursively(): Int {
    var fileCount = 0

    if (exists() && isDirectory) {
        listFiles()?.forEach { child ->
            fileCount += if (child.isDirectory) child.getFileCountRecursively() else 1
        }
    }

    return fileCount
}
```